# How to mock test a function inside save method

Tags: python-3.x, django, unit-testing, testing

I want to send an email each time the status of an object was equal to 13.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    from user_profile.models import SopResumeBuy

    if skip_sop_resume := kwargs.get('skip_sop_resume'):
        del kwargs['skip_sop_resume']

    if(self.status == 13):
        email_sender(
            "subject",
            f"email body",    
        )
    ......
```

the save method will call another email_sender which is a function inside another file.
I want to make sure that the email will be sent.How can i mock the process of sending email?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in Console backend for sending emails.
This will not send out an email but log the content to your console during development.

More information here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/email/#console-backend